# How can I set a larger height for the Facebook Like box?

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like

When using the Like box, the activity stream maxes out when I set the height to 395. I tried to inspect the HTML for the like box and see that the page_stream class has a height attribute but when I tried to override the CSS below, the page_stream div doesn't expand

```
.fan_box .page_stream { height: ; }
```

Docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box

Comment: And what are you trying to achievE?

Answer (score 1):

Its an attribute on the xfbml tag, not in CSS.

EDIT: If you're using the iframe, you must set it in the URL and in the CSS of the iframe.

Comment: As far as I can see (from dropping both the xfbml and iframe versions into my site), this does not fix the issue. Yes you can change the height of the BOX, but the STREAM, as Quy Le is asking about, is not affected by this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

which height parameter are you changing ?
The  generated by the code generator of fb-likebox comes with height specified as 427 at two places, in the iframe height property and in the src as well..
try the following code for facebook platform like box .. here height has been changed to 450 at both places and it works just fine..